# Format percentage to the single digit after the decimal

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting, apache-superset

There is a number like this:

```
77.18%
```

[image]

It should be displayed like this:

```
77.2%
```

I have formatting using:
`.4s` , `.3s`, `.1%` and few other formats which didn't make any change to the format.

Right now the adaptive formatting in Apache superset is giving 2 digits after the decimal, what should be the number format in order to display percentage number with 1 digit after the decimal?

Answer (score 1):

With d3.js, `d3.format(".1%")(0.7718)` will return 77.2%.

You have to give a decimal number in input to the formatter.